# Как заставить работать свайп назад в UINavigationController вместе c DrawerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Использую библиотеку для сайд меню https://github.com/sascha/DrawerController/ - это порт на swift библиотеки https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Библиотека отлично умеет распознавать и разделять свайп назад в UINavigationController и свайп для открытия бокового меню. Но при этом если скрыть NavigationBar свайп назад перестает работать. Если погуглить проблему, то находится [это решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710258/no-swipe-back-when-hiding-navigation-bar-in-uinavigationcontroller). Там советуют сделать **interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil** и оно работает но не вместе с DrawerController.

Видео с багой - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgayLC5a_Ik

Демо проект - https://github.com/nullproduction/SliderApp

Я собрал специальный демо проект чтобы показать багу + снял видео проблемы. На видео я показываю что сначало работает и спайп назад и спайп сайд меню, потом скрываю navigationBar и показываю что свайп назад больше не работает.

Первый делом создал issue в репозитории библиотеки https://github.com/sascha/DrawerController/issues/38 . Мне ответили что это не проблема библиотеки а проблема UIKit и закрыли issue.

Любые идеи как можно решить это проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я скрывал навбар через переменную **navigationBarHidden = true**

Решение оказалось в использовании метода setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false). Видимо внутри метода делаются какие то дополнительные манипуляции отличные от сеттера navigationBarHidden. Меджик!

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.delegate = self
```